# Wildfly Clustered Clickhouse Datasource

Tags: jdbc, wildfly, clickhouse

I'm using clustered clickhouse database. I want to define a wildfly datasource to connect clustered clickhouse. How should I define `Connection URL` in wildfly datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [chproxy](https://github.com/Vertamedia/chproxy), This allows me to load balancing clickhouse cluster. You can configure it to which nodes are in the cluster and use it with one connection url.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use one of the [existing JDBC drivers](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/jdbc/) and define [connection URL](https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-jdbc) like this:

```xml
<datasources ..>
  <datasource ..>
    <!-- .. -->
    <connection-url>jdbc:clickhouse://<host>:<port>[/<database>]</connection-url>
    <!-- .. -->
  </datasource ..>
</datasources>
```

Comment: I have clusteded clickhouse and having more than one connection url. I found [chproxy](https://github.com/Vertamedia/chproxy). This allows me to use load balancing clickhouse cluster.